# WPF: DataGrid event if all cells filled with content

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using a DataGrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection of a custom object. I'm having 2 columns containing rows which need to be filled by the user.

Now I'm having the problem to figure out automatically that the user has entered content to all cells. I tried the DataGrid events but I cannot find one which fires after the cell content is committed and therefore stored in the ObservableColletion.

I'm using PRISM 5 and .NET 4.5.

Has anyone any idea?

EDIT:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EnergyMeasurements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="25" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
    CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visibility="{Binding EnergyDataVisibility}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Number}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1" Binding="{Binding EnergyValue1, StringFormat=\{0:n3\}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2" Binding="{Binding EnergyValue2, StringFormat=\{0:n3\}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Binding="{Binding Unit}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<EnergyMeasurement> EnergyMeasurements
    {
        get { return _energyMeasurements; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _energyMeasurements, value);
            DataUpdated();
        }
    }
```

With the DataUpdated method I want to check if the ObservableCollection is completely filled.

Comment: If your "custom object" is correctly implemented, it's certainly raising PropertyChanged when its properties change. So your viewmodel can easily know what state its children are in. You can also look at validation.

Comment: The setter on `EnergyMeasurements` will be called when you assign a new instance of `ObservableCollection<EnergyMeasurement>` to the property. The DataGrid will never do that. No amount of no-op flags on the  Binding will make it do that.

Comment: The `OberservableCollection` is instanciated during instanciation of the ViewModel. There the Setter is called. But I need the setter to be called if values of the exisitng objects in the collection change.

Comment: @Ed: I have found some solutions on Notification of ObservableCollection items but the subject of performance I wanted to use events of the DataGrid.

Comment: Did you encounter any actual performance issues, or is that just an excuse not to learn WPF properly?

Comment: @Ed: That was what I found as a discussion point on the other threads. I have implemented it as recommended and it works fast and properly now. Thanks.